# d3.js: Drawing arcs between two points on map from file

Tags: d3.js

I am new to d3.js and am trying something simple. I have drawn a world map that reads in file1 and file2. file2 lists airports by an indexID, lat, and lon. file1 pairs the airports by their indexID. I want to draw an arc, line, or anything to connect them. The idea was to produce something like this: http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111116/airports.html with a different data set
but this example was too hard to follow.

The code below correctly draws the map and plots circles for the airports, but remains to be seen how to connect them.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script src="js/topojson.v0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var width = 2000, height = 2000;
    var projection = d3.geo.mercator().center([0, 5]).scale(100).rotate([0, 0]);
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", width).attr("height", height);
    var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);
    var g = svg.append("g");

    d3.json("json/world-110m2.json", function(error, topology) {// load and display the World
        g.selectAll("path").data(topojson.object(topology, topology.objects.countries).geometries).enter().append("path").attr("d", path)
    });

    d3.csv("file1", function(flights) { //Attempt to draw arcs
        var linksByOrigin = {}, countByAirport = {}, locationByAirport = {}, positions = [];

        var arc = d3.geo.greatArc().source(function(d) {
            return locationByAirport[d.source];
        }).target(function(d) {
            return locationByAirport[d.target];
        });

        flights.forEach(function(flight) {
            var origin = flight.origin, destination = flight.destination, links = linksByOrigin[origin] || (linksByOrigin[origin] = []);
            links.push({
                source : origin,
                target : destination
            });
            countByAirport[origin] = (countByAirport[origin] || 0) + 1;
            countByAirport[destination] = (countByAirport[destination] || 0) + 1;
        });

        d3.csv("file2", function(error, data) {// read in and plot the circles
            g.selectAll(".blue.circle").data(data).enter().append("circle").attr("class", "blue circle").attr("cx", function(d) {
                return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[0];
            }).attr("cy", function(d) {
                return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[1];
            });

            g.selectAll("path.arc").data(function(d) {
                return linksByOrigin[data.ctuid] || [];
            }).enter().append("svg:path").attr("class", "arc").attr("d", function(d) {
                return path(arc(d));
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am new to this so the code may be sloppy, but any hints about connecting points pulled from a CSV would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You have code for creating arcs in your example. Does this not work? How does it not work? Do you get an error message?

Comment: Apparently there is code for drawing an arc, but maybe I put it in the wrong places, because the result is just a world map and the points, no arc. No error message, just trying to figure out whether I even drew them correctly and appended them to the map. Thanks!

Comment: You would need to pass the actual data to the bit that draws the arcs, presumably `links`.

Comment: I thought I did that when I pushed the origin and destination onto the source and target. perhaps I am missing something? Thanks!!

Comment: No, you're currently passing in a function (last block in `d3.csv`) that won't do anything.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To draw an arc between points why not use a path with arc directive(A). I too tried greatArc, but din't work. But found an alternate from [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/d3-js/MLZX1AbS7-Y/IxlWHVRlmpYJ) and the alternate is given below:

```
 path.attr("d", function(d) {
    var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
        dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
        dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr +
" 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
  });
```

Replace `path(arc(d))` with the above snippet and replace the x and y values according to your values. This worked like charm for me. Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there a d3-ism for this expression?